# Clarion - Procedure params missing when importing APP into solution from APV

Tags: clarion

I'm new to Clarion and working on a task moving an existing project into Git.

I have used Clarion's internal tooling to export APP files to text (via *Application > Export Application To Text*).  However, upon importing these .APV files back into Clarion, compilation breaks due to a myriad of errors.  Tracing these errors led to the discovery (upon running a diff) that newly imported procedures were missing their parameter signatures.

The same symptoms occur when using Rick Martin's famous Upper Park VC tool via *Upper Park VC > Save App to Version Control*, as well as by right clicking on *Solution Items* in the Solution Explorer and selecting *VC Getting Started > Test Export and re-Import APP Files*.

Overall the question is, how can I modify my export/import process in order to preserve the solution state upon re-importing all APPs into Clarion?

Note: working in Clarion 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the APP file was originally from older version of Clarion and there is a bug in the import from text logic that does not properly handle prototype information in both the old and new format.
I updated the Upper Park VC tool to detect this condition and remove the old prototype format to resolve the issue.